# Split timestamps Spark databricsk python SQL

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have two columns.

| Start | Stop |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-02 18:00:000 | 2021-02-03 02:00:00 |

But I need

| Start | Stop |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-02 18:00:000 | 2021-02-02 23:59:59:997 |
| 2021-02-03 00:00:000 | 2021-02-03 02:00:00 |

I need to calculate daily duration.
I've tried to do it using Spark SQL but without success. If you have any idea using pyspark or Spark sql it will be great.

EDIT :
I've tried by using concat and explode:

| Start | Stop |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-02 18:00:00, 2021-02-03 00:00:00 | 2021-02-02 23:59:59, 2021-02-03 02:00:00 |

but I'm not able to explode multiple columns.

Additionaly I has also cases when date range is more than 1 day.

| Start | Stop |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-02 18:00:000 | 2021-02-08 02:00:00 |

Comment: Can you be more clear in what you want? Do you have a dataframe with `columns = ["start", "stop"]`? What is the input and what is the desired output?

Comment: spark version ?

Comment: Is there a reason why this needs to be done in spark? Can we use pandas and convert it into a spark dataframe? That should be a viable solution if you don't intend to have millions of entries in the output df.

Comment: I have a temp view with those columns. Input - csv, output - temp view/dataframe. Spark version 3.0.1. It can be pandas dataframe also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code.

```
df.show(false)
+-------------------+-------------------+
|start              |stop               |
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2021-02-02 18:00:00|2021-02-03 02:00:00|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

```
df.withColumn("dates",expr("explode(cast(transform(sequence(0,datediff(stop,start)), x -> (case when start > to_timestamp(date_add(start,x)) then start else to_timestamp(date_add(start,x)) end,case when start > to_timestamp(date_add(start,x)) then to_timestamp(unix_timestamp(date_add(start,x+1))-1) else stop end)) as array<struct<start:timestamp,stop:timestamp>>))")).select("dates.*").show(false)
```

```
+-------------------+-------------------+
|start              |stop               |
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2021-02-02 18:00:00|2021-02-02 23:59:59|
|2021-02-03 00:00:00|2021-02-03 02:00:00|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: thank you but I have a temp view and it's not visible for that scala code. I have an error 'not found: value df'

Comment: You can load data into spark dataframe & use above code it will work.

Comment: it works but I need code in python or sql. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can use code inside `expr()` directly in sql. it should work.